# how to get particular tag data from url in python from urllib2

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

I'm very new to python 2.7 and I have a task to read a table in the URL.

I'm getting the data from URL with table. and now the issue is, I need only data but I am getting with tags also.
Please help me. Thank you in advance.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


    response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.somewebsite.com/')
    html = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    tabulka = soup.find("table", {"class" : "defaultTableStyle tableFontMD tableNoBorder"})



    records = [] 
    for row in tabulka.findAll('tr'):
        col = row.findAll('td')

        print col
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use `.text` attribute

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.somewebsite.com/')
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

tabulka = soup.find("table", {"class" : "defaultTableStyle tableFontMD tableNoBorder"})



records = [] 
for row in tabulka.findAll('tr'):
    col = row.findAll('td')

    print [coli.text for coli in col]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and one issue is there, i.e  i am getting every  element with  [u'Type', u'Name', u'Discovered'], but there is no  u in the html

Comment: u means the encoding is unicode. it is not part of the text, you can change to  `coli.text.encode('utf-8')` to get rid of it

Comment: Thank you very much, & guide me one last question, I have an tag in that table row i.e <a href="www.somewebsite.com/quesitons"></a> with some link, & how can i read that link.

Comment: repeat the above with `response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.somewebsite.com/quesitons')`

Comment: Actually the html format is like this. <td> text</td <td><a href="link">text</a></td><td>text></td> and I am able to get the text of all td's but i also required the link. at atime how can I get that.

Comment: coli.find('a').get('href') will return href of a